# Почему появляется ошибка Instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, clean-architecture

У меня есть метод в репозитории, который изменяет значение одного поля, перед этим проверив наличие ентити:

```
public async Task<Post?> DeleteAsync(Guid id)
{
    var entity = await context.Posts.FindAsync(id);
    if (entity is null) return null;
    
    entity.Status = Statuses.Deleted;

    await using var transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
    await transaction.CreateSavepointAsync("transaction");
    try
    {
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        await transaction.CommitAsync();
        return mapper.Map<Post>(entity);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        await transaction.RollbackToSavepointAsync("transaction");
        return default;
    }
}
```

Насколько корректно делать проверку на null на entity уровне? У меня есть ещё менеджер постов, который как раз вызывает метод `DeleteAsync` и кажется, что лучше в нём сделать получение модельки из базы, потом передать её в `DeleteAsync`, смапить модельку в ентити и произвести изменения. Как-то так:

```
// слой менеджера
public async Task<Post?> DeleteAsync(Guid postId)
{
    var post = await postsRepository.GetAsync(postId);
    if (post is null) return null;
    
    return await postsRepository.DeleteAsync(post);
}

// слой entity
public async Task<Post?> DeleteAsync(Post post)
{
    var entity = mapper.Map<PostEntity>(post);
    entity.Status = Statuses.Deleted;

    await using var transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
    await transaction.CreateSavepointAsync("transaction");
    try
    {
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        await transaction.CommitAsync();
        return mapper.Map<Post>(entity);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        await transaction.RollbackToSavepointAsync("transaction");
        return default;
    }
}
```

Но в таком случае появляется ошибка:

```
The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked
```

Её можно как-то поправить, чтобы использовать второй вариант?

Я тут первый вариант с одной проверкой на null показал, но в проекте есть метод, где 3 разные проверки. И, кажется, что это уже метод проверки на null, а не на обновление свойства entity. Поэтому первый вариант не подходит.

Comment: Вам обязательно надо шарить контекст между методами репозитория? Также я бы это `public async Task<Post?> DeleteAsync(Post post)` переписал на это `public async Task DeleteAsync(Guid id)`. Плюс не ясно, зачем вам транзакции тут, EF вроде по умолчанию выполняет сохранение в транзакции.

Comment: Если сильно хочется второй вариант, то можно попробовать `context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;` и потом сохраняйте. Только я не уверен, чтото вызывающий код вам не поломает логику, если вдруг поменяет несколько полей.

Comment: @tym32167 почитал про транзакции, действительно, тут можно их не использовать. Но если бы я в `DeleteAsync(Post post)` не только менял статус, но и делал бы что-то еще с какой-либо таблицей. Тогда нужно было бы обернуть всё в транзакцию?

Comment: Дело не в том, сколько полей вы меняете, а в том, сколько раз вы вызываете SaveChanges,  потому что по умолчанию этот вызов [уже обернут в транзакцию](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions). То есть для одного вызова нет смысла руками транзакции писать, там транзакция автоматом уже есть.